# inter-device communication

Tags: ipad, ios, gamekit

I am looking at device to device communications and need some direction.

I have a series of applications that will need to update each other with information, or simply tell each other there is a new dataset that is ready to be read and updated on the local machine.

I was thinking about using something out of the gamekit, but I want to know if this is the best approach.

Currently, I have a few iPads in a doctors office, everything is working OK, but the doctors are not seeing updates between devices when a user makes an update to the same patient, I need the other devices that are looking at the same patient to be updated/notified there are changes, and I can reload the data from the database.

Each device belongs to a practice, and I have the MAC addresses of each device.

Comment: This is nothing to do with Xcode - Xcode is just an IDE - your question is apparently about iPads and iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [Game Kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/) is the way to go. Game Kit will handle almost everything for you.

Comment: rock on...  i thought so, but wanted some additional feedback.  thank you

Comment: @pithhelmet - Glad I could help. Feel free to post other questions if you have any. I really suggest reading the GameKit docs, they're very informative and have some great code samples. Good luck!